# Block touch propagation to another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a child view that puts itself over other sibling views. The problem is that when I touch it, the sibling also reacts at the touch event. How can I disable touch propagation on the underlying sibling views?

Answer (score 3):

In theory, if you overlap the tab bar with a view with exclusiveTouch = YES, it should not respond to this touch, either.

Try setting exclusiveTouch = YES and, maybe, add the overlay view as a subview of tabBarController.view (and bring it to the front).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your views react on the same selector. Look at InterfaceBuilder to the Connections Inspector which action reacts on which event. If this fails, you can stop a view of reacting on user interaction with:

```
UIView userInteractionEnabled
```

Comment: Thanks for replaying. The real code is a little complicated but I will try to explain. I have a child UIView that shows it self  over the entire screen, overflowing a UITabBar. But the TabBar reacts at the tap event even you can't see it. It is a little tricky to go back in the UIVIew hierarchy and tell to disable the TabBar User Interaction Enabled. I wandered if it's possible to say to the child view to block propagation to underlying views.